# BSD Packet Filter Redirect Internal traffic

Tags: mac, firewall, bsd

I'm using OSX Yosemite with Packet Filter (BSD). Is there a way to redirect internal originating traffic (let's say from en1) to lo0 on a specific port for specific destinations? rdr from what I understood is used only for incoming packets.

Thx